# How to restore default scrolling behaviour on arcGIS?

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel, arcgis-js-api, stoppropagation

I have one issue using a map with arcGIS API:

When the mouse pointer is above the map, default page scrolling is blocked. I know that I can suppress map zooming on scroll with stopPropagation() on mouse-wheel event, but that leads only to disabling zoom. The page still does not move on scroll...

That causes bad user experience, especially when using large / full-screen maps inside a page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling scroll-zooming on the view using code below ([like the esri demo here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=view-disable-scroll-zoom)) does not prevent the DOM element `wheel` event to be triggered which prevent the default page scrolling;

```
  //this prevent the mapView to zoom on wheel but does not make the page to scroll as wanted
  view.on("mouse-wheel", function(event) {
    // disable mouse wheel scroll zooming on the view
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

So what you need to do, is to add a wheel event listener on the DOM element that handle the esri wheel event and then do a [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) so the esri wheel event that cancel the default page scrolling would not be triggered.

With the API v.4.9 the DOM element that you have to use have the `esri-view-surface` class

```
  var viewSurfaceElem = document.getElementsByClassName("esri-view-surface")[0];
  viewSurfaceElem.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
```

See live demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQLwwm

Comment: That´s it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That worked well.

Now I have another similar problem: Since I am only able to embed a client´s app via iFrame, there is the same scrollling issue. I could check the '✓ Prevent map scroll' option in the settings, but the page still stops scrolling when the mouse cursor is above the map. Since the iframe is embedded in full screen size, it block page scrolling completely.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question, can you provide a demo of the problem? From what I understand, won't you just have to add `overflow-y: auto;` to the iframe css?